# PHP: How to delete specific characters in a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have this string:

```
$str = 'TLAGMSC1-MSX,"LABEL=TMXCABINLC, TG=789",0.028,0,53.488';
```

I'd like to delete:

> `, TG=789` //the 3 numbers here will vary since the string will have different values everytime

How can I accomplish this? Maybe using regex?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, use a regex. Right tool the job here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are replacing specific characters including some that change, regex is your tool.

The expression you need is `/, TG=\d{3}/` for "exactly these characters, then exactly three digits".

Just use

```
preg_replace('/, TG=\d{3}/', '', $str);
```

as the syntax is

```
preg_replace(pattern, replacement, subject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace`

```
var $repl = preg_replace('/, +TG=\d{3}/', "", $str)
//=> TLAGMSC1-MSX,"LABEL=TMXCABINLC",0.028,0,53.488
```